# Neo4J - Return everything from node but property key

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have generalized cypher that returns different types of nodes whose property names may vary from which I need to exclude any property name called "password". I've tried using a CASE statement inside of EXTRACT, FILTER and REDUCE but I am not getting anywhere.

```
RETURN reduce(props = {}, x IN keys(stateNode) |
    case when x <> "password" then
        props + {x: stateNode[x]}
    else
        props + {"password": "changed"}
    end
)
```

This obviously won't work but I am not sure how else to do it. I don't have the luxury of knowing what the other property names are so I cant explicitly return every property excluding "password" property.

Answer (score 0):

If it is OK to return an array of arrays (where each inner array contains a key/value pair), then you can use something like this:

```
RETURN REDUCE(s = [], x IN keys(stateNode) |
  s + [[x, (CASE WHEN x = "password" THEN "changed" ELSE stateNode[x] END)]]
) AS props;
```

The result would look something like:

```
[["name","Fred"],["age",22],["password","changed"]]
```

Comment: I guess I could work with this, thanks! So is there really no way to merge two objects in neo4j? If by chance you could, can I declare an empty object, set a dynamic property name using bracket notation and its value, and then merge that object with the accumulator object?